# Import-csv into Active Directory

Tags: powershell, import, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I am following [this guide](http://blogs.technet.com/b/hot/archive/2012/04/26/directory-sync-cannot-update-distribution-group-after-office-365-migration.aspx)

I was able to export the Distribution Groups to a CSV, and edit the CSV, but when using

```
Import-csv c:\displayname.csv | foreach-object {set-adgroup -identity $_.SamAccountName -displayname $_.displayname}
```

To import the modifications, I get:

> Set-ADGroup : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The
>   argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.

I have tried variations on the theme and no change. Also, I needed to use `-Credential domain\username` when exporting, I have tried adding that and variations of that when trying to import the changes back...no difference.

1) Wouldn't I need to authenticate?

2) What am I missing as far as importing the CSV? I feel it is simple, like some extra info:  OU, DC, Credential etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error just indicate that `$_.SamAccountName` is not valued do you try first to see these values ?

Modifying the CSV file you perhaps corrupt it, your command line works for me.

---

Perhaps your problem is in the encoding or in the form of your CSV file you can try first to create one with PowerShell :

```
Get-ADGroup  -Properties samaccountname,displayname -LDAPFilter "(cn=*sec)" | Export-Csv gp.csv
```

And then to compare with your own. Here I just extract a few fields from groups containing sec in their names.

Comment: Thank you for posting and confirming it works for you. I have not yet been successful myself. I will post back with anything I find. I can confirm that both the CSV and AD have the proper names. I have also recreated the file using Excel instead of OpenOffice with no difference. Thanks again for your help @JPBlanc

Comment: You should have a try first exporting a CSV file just to see what PowerShell is expecting.

Comment: That comment you provided was the answer! Once I got an example from an export, everything worked as expected. Thanks for your help.